# Generics comparing objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, generics, arraylist

I'm trying to create a generic class that compares objects in an array list and returns the largest. My issue is that I'm not quite sure I understand completely how generics work.

Measurable:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
   Describes any class whose objects can be measured.
*/

public abstract class Measurable<T>{

abstract double getMeasure();

    public static <T extends Measurable<T>> T getLargest(ArrayList<T> objects){
        T largest = objects.get(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i ++){
            if(largest.getMeasure() == objects.get(i).getMeasure()){
                largest = objects.get(i);
            }
        }
        return largest;     
    }

}
```

Box:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Box extends Measurable {

    private Rectangle box;
    private static ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles;

    public Box(){
        box = new Rectangle();
        rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Rectangle> create(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            box = new Rectangle((int) Math.random(), (int) Math.random());
            rectangles.add(box);
        }
        return rectangles;
    }

    @Override
    public double getMeasure() {
        double area = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < rectangles.size(); i++){
            area = rectangles.get(i).getWidth()*rectangles.get(i).getHeight();
        }
        return area;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Box b = new Box();
        b.getLargest(b.create());
    }
}
```

I'm coming across an issue where it says "The method getLargest(ArrayList) in the type Measurable is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)" but shouldn't I be able to use any object for the getLargest class?

Comment: you expect that `ArrayList` contains objects extending Measurable class, `Rectangle` does not extend it

Comment: why does `Measureable` have a type parameter `T`? It doesn't seem to be used anywhere in the class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote it, `getLargest` expects the objects *passed to it* in the `List` to implement `Measurable`, but `java.awt.Rectangle` does not.

When you write

```
public static <T extends Measurable<T>> T getLargest(ArrayList<T> objects){
```

that declares a `T` that is *different*, but named the same, as the `T` in the `Measurable` class as a whole, which is likely to lead to total confusion.

If you actually replace `T` with `Rectangle` in your code, you can see that you're trying to call `Rectangle.getMeasure()`, which is a method that does not exist.

Comment: Okay so since I'm referencing java.awt.Rectangle it does not use Measurable. So if I want to use Rectangles as my object I need to pretty much create my own Rectangle class which would reference Measurable.

Comment: Or you could be instead writing a `Measurer` class, which has a method `getMeasure(T t)`, and invoking that.  That might make more sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure where generics come into play here. It seems like you want to make a bunch of shapes that are derived from a base class Measurable. You also want the abstract class to hold some code for working with Measurable subclasses. Basically you need to make a subclass that implements Measurable. I think what you want a Box class like the one below.

```
public class Box extends Measurable {

    private double width;
    private double height;

    public Box(double width, double height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getMeasure() {
        double area = width*height;
        return area;
    }
}
```